# DKIM settings with Amazon SES not finding primary domain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, email, dkim

I'm attempting to send email via Amazon SES with a custom domain.  I have one domain that works and the DKIM headers that come to my gmail account look like:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
    dkim=pass header.i=@domain1.tld header.s=g4rjrmit5ppzy4wkr4okghzfauvxq7q7 header.b=Vl5caVVD;
    dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=hsbnp7p3ensaochzwyq5wwmceodymuwv header.b=nVdcG6Mz;
```

However, on the other domain (let's say domain2.tld) I only see the SES DKIM:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
    dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=hsbnp7p3ensaochzwyq5wwmceodymuwv header.b=OEoWQF7R;
```

Ultimately on the second domain SPF also passes but DMARC fails:

```
dmarc=fail (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=domain2.tld
```

Where have I missed setting something up?  Why doesn't SES or the receiving SMTP server find the the domain2.tld DKIM?  I've gone through DNS and it *looks* the same but obviously I'm missing something.  I will say that on the second domain online DKIM checkers fail unless I specify the selector.  On the first domain I'm able to find them without a problem but that one uses a common "s1" selector.

Can you point me in a direction to dig some more?

Comment: Did you configure AWS SES to use DKIM for the second domain?